# Is there a way to show find locate results in a tree?

Tags: linux, search, tree, grep, locate

Basically, I want to search for files and directories whose names contain for instance "ajax", and show the results in a tree that includes the parent directories.

A very dumb approach is to use this :

```
tree | grep ajax
```

This gives somehow an idea of what I'd like, but I guess that's entirely messed up in reality because there are no lines containing the parent directories.

Of course, this

```
locate ajax | tree
```

doesn't work, tree doesn't "take" the results.

More sadly, tree doesn't recognize **--prune**

```
tree -P '*ajax*' --prune
```

on my ubuntu server. Is there a solution to do this ?

EDIT :

For reference, the following command would have been the way to do it, given --prune worked :

```
tree -P '*ajax*' --prune --matchdirs
```

This works perfectly well in my archlinux at home, tree v1.7. The server version is tree 1.5.3. I guess Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS is quite outdated now :(

EDIT 2:

I tried to see in proposed dist, but to not avail. So I guess I'll have to do with a grep / sed solution...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you means
`tree -P '*ajax*' --prune`